# Exact matching with Question mark in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to find string `?Allen` in the string array but there is question mark in keyword and it causes some problems. 
I write this code to find string in array

```
@arr = ("My name is ?Allen",
"My name is ?Allens",
"My name is s?Allen",
"My name is s?Allens",
"My name is ?allen");
$keyword = "?Allen";
for (my $i=0; $i <= 4; $i++){
  if ($arr[$i] =~ /\b$keyword\b/){
      print "str $i = match\n";
  }else{
      print "str $i = no\n";
  }
}
```

finally I get this result

```
str 0 = match
str 1 = no
str 2 = match
str 3 = no
str 4 = no
```

but I want to find only first index array as matching string like this:

```
str 0 = match
str 1 = no
str 2 = no
str 3 = no
str 4 = no
```

Comment: Try `/(?<!\S)\Q$keyword\E(?!\S)/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. It's worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your regex contains non-word special chars that you need to quote before using them in the actual pattern. Also, the fact that the special chars can appear at the leading/trailing positions means you cannot expect `\b` to always work the same (since its meaning is context dependent). Thus, you may fix the code with

```
/(?<!\S)\Q$keyword\E(?!\S)/
```

where

- `(?<!\S)` - requires a whitespace char or start of string before
- `\Q$keyword\E` - a literal search string (see [*Quoting Metacharacters*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters))
- `(?!\S)` - that should be followed with a whitespace or end of string.

Another alternative for `\Q...\E` ([mentioned by Dave Cross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975683/exact-matching-with-question-mark-in-perl/39975886?noredirect=1#comment67234010_39975886)) is using [*`quotemeta`*](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html):

> This is the internal function implementing the `\Q` escape in double-quoted strings.

Comment: `$keyword = quotemeta "?Allen"` would be another alternative.